# How to require a C++ template parameter to have some methods with a given signature?

Tags: c++

I would like to define a class, which has one template parameter `T`. I would like to make sure, that `T` has a `void Update(uint32_t)` and a `int32_t GetResult() const` method. I know that the user will get an error when I try to call one of these methods, but I would like to make sure (possibly with a static assert) that they exists as soon as I can.

I was only able to find solutions to check if the class `T` is derived from some other class `U`, but that is not what I want. I wold like to allow any class, which has the mentioned methods.

Comment: If the compiler supports C++ 17 then use the require clause.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I think you mean C++20.

Comment: What do you mean by "as soon as I can"? Do you want the user to get an error message that refers to line 1 instead of line 2457?

Comment: If you want the user to pass you an object and you are just using one or two functions on this object, consider just passing the function(s) instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need concepts for this, although those help.
This code will happily works in C++11.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>

using namespace std;

struct A {
    void Update(uint32_t);
    int32_t GetResult() const;
};
struct B {

};
using namespace std;

template <typename T, typename = typename enable_if<
    is_same<decltype(&T::Update), void (T::*)(uint32_t)>::value &&
    is_same<decltype(&T::GetResult), int32_t (T::*)() const>::value
    >::type>
struct CLS 
{
};

using namespace std;

int main() {
    CLS<A> a; // works
    CLS<B> b; // fails to compile
    return 0;
}
```

Note, that this code checks **exact** function signature, so `Update(int)` won't pass.

EDIT: added const to getResult

Answer (score 3):

With concepts introduced in C++20, this is trivial with requires expressions and requires clauses. In the code, the keyword `requires` appears twice. The first introduces a requires clause, and the second introduces a requires expression.

```
template <typename T>
    requires requires (T& a, const T& b, uint32_t i) {
        a.Update(i);
        {b.GetResult()} -> int32_t;
    }
void foo(T& x)
{
    // ...
}
```

([live test](https://wandbox.org/permlink/iEFd8VSM6x34SyuO))

Prior to C++20, you can write a trait class that deploys SFINAE:

```
template <typename T>
class foo_traits {
    static auto check(...) -> std::false_type;
    template <typename U>
    static auto check(U x) -> decltype((void)x.Update(uint32_t{}), std::true_type{});
public:
    static constexpr bool has_update = decltype(check(std::declval<T>()))::value;
};
```

Now you can use it like:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T& x)
{
    static_assert(foo_traits<T>::has_update, "blah blah blah");
}
```

Or:

```
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<foo_traits<T>::has_update> foo(T& x)
{
}
```

([live test](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2TrG9SfwDTBilVDy))

`GetResult` can be handled analogously.

---

Note: the above code only ensures that the expressions are valid, rather than ensuring the precise signatures. Of course you can also do that. Here's the approach with concepts:

```
template <typename T>
    requires requires (T& a, const T& b, uint32_t i) {
        a.Update(i);
        {&T::GetResult} -> std::int32_t (T::*)() const;
    }
void foo(T& x)
{
    // ...
}
```

Radosław Cybulski's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56618426) already shows how to do this without concepts, so I am not showing it again.

Comment: Just nitpicking, but this does not ensure precise signature that OP asked for, only that those expressions do not generate any errors. So `int Update(float)` will compile  just fine.

Comment: @Quimby Good point, I have updated my answer to address this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a `static_assert`, that is possible:

```
static_assert(static_cast< void (T::*)(uint32_t) >(&T::update), 
              "Need void T::update(uint32_t");
```

The cast checks if overload resolution is possible, i.e. if the right signature is present.